# Attempt to Upgrade is failing due to unstable mfc6490cwlpr:i386

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, dpkg

I am attempting to upgrade to the most recent Ubuntu OS but i am being stopped with warning that mfc6490cwlpr:i386 is in a very bad inconsistent state. the warning suggests that I should reinstall before I remove this pkg. 
The following is my attempt to do so.

```
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
(Reading database ... 284218 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mfc6490cwlpr:i386 ...
start: Unknown job: lpd
dpkg: error processing mfc6490cwlpr:i386 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:

mfc6490cwlpr:i386
me@mycomp-Studio-1737:~$ ^C
kingston@kingston-Studio-1737:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for ME: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mfc6490cwcupswrapper:i386:
 mfc6490cwcupswrapper:i386 depends on mfc6490cwlpr; however:
  Package mfc6490cwlpr:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing mfc6490cwcupswrapper:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mfc6490cwcupswrapper:i386
me@mycomp-Studio-1737:~$ sudo apt-get install mfc6490cwcupswrapper:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mfc6490cwcupswrapper:i386
```

Needless to say... I have had no luck. 
Can anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest visiting the [Brother Linux Driver](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-6490CW) page and download the required *.deb files. Then use `dpkg -i mfc*.deb` (if you are on i386 -- on 64bit you would need `dpkg -i --force-all mfc*.deb` instead) -- which fulfils the request of "reinstall it". Hopefully, after that the package no longer is in a "bad state", and you can upgrade. In the worst case, you may have to uninstall all the brother packages, then upgrade, and finally re-install (and re-configure) them.

I created an [installation script](http://pastebin.com/VnifBPF0) to ease the installation of Brother printer drivers which can be used for a clean installation -- and was successfully used for an MFC-9120CN on Ubuntu 12.4 64bit. It requires the packages downloaded from above mentioned driver page to reside within the same directory, and should work on 32bit and 64bit installations as well, taking care for all dependencies and quoting necessary steps.

Comment: Izzy I have attempted your suggestion with this result "My Comp:~$ dpkg -i --force-all mfc*.deb
dpkg: error: operation requires read/write access to dpkg status area"

Comment: @user74612 in the beginning, you forgot to include the command executed. If I interprete things correctly, you used `apt-get` to install the packages -- which is not possible, as they are not included in any repository. You must use `dpkg` instead. I posted an installation script I created to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VnifBPF0)